# Error reading disk drive /tmp at boot

Tags: tmp

First I want to say thank you in advance because I have been reading all the forum entries about similar problems and I have had no luck in solving this one.

I have a Dell Inspiron with a phony Windows 7 OS; it's currently open to viruses and I'm trying to use a different, more secure OS, such as Linux. I'm in a CIS 101 class but still a noob (beginner) when it comes to computer language, so I would need step by step instructions on how to solve this problem.

Here's my problem: I installed Ubuntu on my comp using both a DVD and USB flash stick. I can select Ubuntu as the OS but it gives me the message: `error reading disk drive /tmp is not responding`. I need to know what is the problem is exactly and what I need to do to bypass this or manually recover the /tmp. Once again thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with the swap partition or some other partitions you need to update the fstab file

Open terminal(ctrl+Alt+T) and enter command

sudo blkid

you will get partitions and their UUID number

now open another Terminal and enter the below commands

sudo gedit /etc/fstab

In that file compare the UUID number of swap(it will be under the comment "#swap was on /sda/sd1(some number) during installation" ) with the UUID number of swap in first terminal if both are different then copy the UUID number from first terminal and paste it in the fstab file under #swap in palce of old UUID number

save and reboot

dont mess with UUID number under '# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation' its ubuntu drives if you change that ubuntu wont boot